# put the small icon from left_Top tp left_bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

you see the pic ,there is a small icon at left_Top i want to put at left_bottom,how to do. my xml:

[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:padding="1dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewThumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageTick"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sina" >
</ImageView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewThumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageTick"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sina" >
</ImageView>
```

```
add android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Relative layout`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:padding="1dip">

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageViewThumb"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="fitXY" >
   </ImageView>

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageTick"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```